# Azure SAP HANA Backup - hdbuserstore invalid system key

Tags: azure, backup, hana

I am trying to run the pre-reg script for Azure HANA backup but keep coming up with the error in below image.

If I open the terminal and run `su SIDadm` and `hdbuserstore list` I get the message  (screenshot below)/

> DATA FILE : /usr/sap/SID/home/.hdb/.../SSFS_HDB.DAT

[image: Result 1]

Also if I run the `hdbuserstore set system` command I get a `no match` result.

If I open the terminal from `/hana/shared/SID/hdbclient` and run `hdbuserstore` then I can see the system key:

[image: Result]

[image: pre-registration script error]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshots it appears that the `hdbuserstore` entries have been made as user **root** (the location of the SSFS_HDB-files gives this away: `/root/.hdb/...`).

Since the `hdbuserstore` information is specific to the OS-user, the entries stored as root will not be available to the **sidadm** user.

The solution for this is: create the required entries as **sidadm** or use the `-u <username>` parameter to set the entries for the user when running as **root**.

Comment: Thanks, I will attempt the above and see where I end up. :-)

Comment: Just a quick update, it turns out that the command did not like the complexity of the password (special characters) and once I put the SYSTEM password in quotes "password" it accepted the command and was able to complete the rest of the tasks.